# What are the difference between these type assertion or casting methods in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

I'm fairly new with TypeScript, could you explain what are the difference between these methods of type assertion:

```
// 1. Using :
let myStr: string;

// 2. Using as
let strLength = (myStr as string).length;

// 3. Using <> on left side
let strLength = <string>myStr.length;

// 4. Using <> on right side
let myObs: Observable<number>
```

and when to use one over the others?
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
// 1. Using :
let myStr: string;  // declaring a variable with its type as string

// 2. Using as
let strLength = (myStr as string).length; // casting a variable's type to string type using `as` keyword,but here type of strLength is determine by type assertion as there is no explicit type defined.

// 3. Using <> on left side
let strLength = <string>myStr.length;  // same as 2 above but using <>

// 4. Using <> on right side
let myObs: Observable<number>  // Observable is a generic type you can specify its type(T) in  Observable<T>, here it is `number` type.
```

However there is an ambiguity in the language grammar when using <> style assertions in JSX, hence recommended to use `as`  for consistency.

Typescript casting :

https://acdcjunior.github.io/typescript-cast-object-to-other-type-or-instanceof.html

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Typescript generic type : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: So, using `<>` on right side is not considered assertion or casting?

Comment: @xcode nope , it's the syntax for using generics same as in C#.

Comment: does generic similar to interface?

Comment: @xcode check the link of generics in my answer, No generics is not like interface. If you want the type of a variable to be reusable in a certain scenario then you can use generic depending on the type restriction of `T` on Observable<T> , For example if we specify T as `number` then it will only allow Observable<number> to be assigned to that variable. This type check will be done at compile time by typescript.

Comment: Casting should generally be avoided as it works around typescript, `myStr` is supposed to be a string then it should be typed as such. If `myStr` is showing up as something other than a string and casting is required it generally hints at a code smell.

Answer (score 7):

The first one, you're setting the type of the variable as a string, so if you try to set the variable with something else than a string it will throw an error

```
let myStr: string
myStr = 1 // not working
myStr = 'Hello' // Working
```

the second one is a cast, the variable has a type but you want to use it as another type. Example, a function return an object but you know it's a string and want to use it as a string:

```
let myStr = helloWorld() //return an object but you know it's a string
strLength = (myStr as string).length //get length of the string
```

The third one is the same than above

and last one, you're setting the type of the object contained in your Observable
so in your example, myObs is waiting for string and if you had something else it won't work, it's generic you can put whatever you want

```
Observable<T>
```

Some links
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score -2):

1. `let myStr: string;`

causes the subsequent attempts to use the length property on myStr to fail with a cannot find length of undefined because although myStr is typed as string, it is not initialized to a value.

Use it as

```
let myStr: string='';
```

2. `let strLength = (myStr as string).length;`

is interesting because the test shows that despite the cast to string, it is still a number because of the length property.

[image]

3. `let strLength1 = <string>myStr.length;`

same as above. Casting it as string has no meaning because the value returned to the non-typed variable is a number

[image]

4. `let myObs: Observable<number>`

Observable is typed as a number but not initialized. Assuming that Observable is an object with a generic type then it should be initialized as

```
let myObs= new Observable<number>(10)
```

with a parameterized constructor of type number as below:

```
export class Observable<number> {
    private value: number;
    constructor(x: number) { this.value = x; }
    }
```

Comment: `(myStr as string)` isn't a cast, it's a type assertion. So you are telling the compiler that even though it doesn't know for sure that `myStr` is a `string` you know better and it should believe you. It doesn't actually affect the object itself.

Comment: Coming from C# and since Typescript has many C# features, I'd say it is.