# typescript as versus normal type declaration?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Does this normal declaration

```
let myArrayObject: Array<{id: String, name: String}> = [];
```

different than using `as` like

```
const myArrayObject = [] as Array<{id: String, name: String}>
```

I find as is more readable though.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner I'm asking a comparison question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the difference between these type assertion or casting methods in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818305/what-are-the-difference-between-these-type-assertion-or-casting-methods-in-types)

Comment: Hi @NadielyJade if you're satisfied with my answer please accept! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The as keyword is used as type assertion in typescript

Comment: what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The normal declaration is assigning a type to the object. "as" is casting the object to have a specific type, no matter the type inferred by TypeScript automatically.

For example, let's look at the following code.

```
interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    occupation: string;
}

const myself = {name:"andy"} as User
```

The object myself does not have all the fields required by the "User" interface. But we can tell typescript to treat "myself" as a "User". This is useful in many cases, for example if there's some function that is expecting "User" objects as input but we want it to accept an object that does not have all the properties defined in "User".

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: Exactly what @codealigned pointed out..

Comment: The difference is "as" tells typescript to treat the object as a certain type (as opposed to the type that typescript originally would infer).